# Hide other Msg Boxes that pop up in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following code looks for certain text strings in a column and gives a msg box whenever something matches. The code looks for more than one text string, so if I have "X" AND "y" in one column and the code looks for both text strings, then two msg boxes will appear. I only want the first msg box to show and hide the rest. Is there a way to do this?

In other words, code looks for multiple text strings, pops up msg boxes if text strings match. More than one text string will definitely match, but I want only the first box to appear, and hide the rest.

Thanks

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim icounter As Long
Dim icounter1 As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim MSG As String, ans As Variant
For icounter = 2 To 31

    If Cells(icounter, 2) = "Job Code Name" Then
       MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. PS Group" & vbNewLine & "2. Level" & vbNewLine & "3. Box Level" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")

ElseIf Cells(icounter, 2) = "Personnel Area" Then
       MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Personnel Subarea" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")

ElseIf Cells(icounter, 2) = "Line of Sight" Then
       MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. 1 Up Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")

ElseIf Cells(icounter, 2) = "Title of Position" Then
       MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Job Code Name" & vbNewLine & "2. PS Group" & vbNewLine & "3. PS Level" & vbNewLine & "4. Box Level" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")

ElseIf Cells(icounter, 2) = "Company Code Name" Then
       MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Cost Center" & vbNewLine & "2. Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & "3. 1 Up Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & "4. Personnel Area" & vbNewLine & "5. Location" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")

ElseIf Cells(icounter, 2) = "Function" Then
       MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Sub Function" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")

Else

End If

Next icounter
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're after, but you can exit the loop with `Exit For`.

Comment: Just `exit sub` or `exit for` where you want to. in your case after every `MsgBox`-call

Comment: how do i edit the code so the loop stops after the first match? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use Select Case instead of all the If...ElseIf stuff. Just reading the comments. Apparently you want to exit the For loop as well so add `Exit For`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim icounter As Long
    Dim icounter1 As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Dim MSG As String, ans As Variant
    For icounter = 2 To 31
        Select Case Cells(icounter, 2)
            Case "Job Code Name"
                MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. PS Group" & vbNewLine & "2. Level" & vbNewLine & "3. Box Level" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
                Exit For
            Case "Personnel Area"
                MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Personnel Subarea" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
                Exit For
            Case "Line of Sight"
                MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. 1 Up Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
                Exit For
            Case "Title of Position" 
                MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Job Code Name" & vbNewLine & "2. PS Group" & vbNewLine & "3. PS Level" & vbNewLine & "4. Box Level" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
                Exit For
            Case "Company Code Name" 
                MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Cost Center" & vbNewLine & "2. Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & "3. 1 Up Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & "4. Personnel Area" & vbNewLine & "5. Location" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
                Exit For
            Case "Function" 
                MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Sub Function" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next icounter
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I am noticing that if I enter a text string other than what's listed above, the message box will still pop up and display a msg box corresponding to the one before. I.e. - > If I have a row with "Personnel Area" and another row "blahblah", I'll get a msg pop up for "Personnel Area". is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Also, I am noticing that changes in other columns still prompt the msg box.

Comment: I used your answer but it fired whenever I made an edit to any cell in the sheet. To avoid this, I added this line of code before `Select Case Cells(icounter, 2)`:

    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(icounter, 2)) Is Nothing Then


This edit has made the msg box pop up only when cells change to the string text I inputted, i.e. company code name

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you another refactoring in your code. Since you are using a Worksheet event, every time you change a cell content it will fire that event, so I believe you add Application.EnableEvents = False before your For loop and Application.EnableEvents = True after it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim icounter As Long
    Dim icounter1 As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
Dim MSG As String, ans As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False
For icounter = 2 To 31
    Select Case Cells(icounter, 2)
        Case "Job Code Name"
            MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. PS Group" & vbNewLine & "2. Level" & vbNewLine & "3. Box Level" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
            Exit For
        Case "Personnel Area"
            MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Personnel Subarea" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
            Exit For
        Case "Line of Sight"
            MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. 1 Up Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
            Exit For
        Case "Title of Position"
            MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Job Code Name" & vbNewLine & "2. PS Group" & vbNewLine & "3. PS Level" & vbNewLine & "4. Box Level" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
            Exit For
        Case "Company Code Name"
            MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Cost Center" & vbNewLine & "2. Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & "3. 1 Up Line of Sight" & vbNewLine & "4. Personnel Area" & vbNewLine & "5. Location" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
            Exit For
        Case "Function"
            MsgBox ("Please note you may need to add in additional attributes under this field" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. Sub Function" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add in these additional fields as needed")
            Exit For
    End Select
Next icounter

Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Tim's answer but it fired whenever I made an edit to any cell in the sheet. To avoid this, I added this line of code before `Select Case Cells(icounter, 2)`:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(icounter, 2)) Is Nothing Then
```

This edit has made the msg box pop up only when cells change to the string text I inputted, i.e. company code name